# Finding the bounding area in ImageMagick alpha image

Tags: php, imagemagick

I'm taking some images and, using ImageMagick via PHP scripts, removing their backgrounds as well as I can.  Lots of the images have solid color backgrounds, so it works pretty well.  The only problem is that the output image retains the original dimensions, full of empty space.  Is there a way in ImageMagick to determine the bounds of the non-transparent content and adjust the canvas accordingly?

[image: Representation of the question]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ImageMagick processing options is [-trim](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#trim); which, evaluates the pixel at each corner, and crops-out similar pixels. PHP's [Imagick::trimImage](http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.trimimage.php) method should work. Additional examples can be found at ImageMagick's "[Auto-Crop"](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#trim) article.

[image: With green field] source

`convert -trim source.png desired.png`

[image: Trimmed image] desired